# Postman Return Body Response ( thumbnail url) into Flutter json map into Dart object and it doesnt work on Grid view Builder

Tags: flutter, return, postman, response

I am a beginner in flutter app development and I want to display thumb images into flutter grid view builder. My postman return response is 200. This is the response from postman
[image]

This is my flutter code. I donot know what i am doing wrong.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $bearer_token'
  };
  var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stg/assets'));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  }
  else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
  
  
}


List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Photo {
  List<Assets> assets;

  Photo({this.assets});

  Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['assets'] != null) {
      assets = new List<Assets>();
      json['assets'].forEach((v) {
        assets.add(new Assets.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.assets != null) {
      data['assets'] = this.assets.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Assets {
  String assetId;
  String createdAt;
  String description;
  bool isPrivate;
  bool isThumbnailGenerated;
  Metadata metadata;
  String name;
  Null sharedBy;
  int sizeInBytes;
  List<String> tags;
  String thumbnailUrl;
  String title;
  String type;
  String uploadDate;
  String uploadStatus;

  Assets(
      {this.assetId,
        this.createdAt,
        this.description,
        this.isPrivate,
        this.isThumbnailGenerated,
        this.metadata,
        this.name,
        this.sharedBy,
        this.sizeInBytes,
        this.tags,
        this.thumbnailUrl,
        this.title,
        this.type,
        this.uploadDate,
        this.uploadStatus});

  Assets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    assetId = json['asset_id'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    description = json['description'];
    isPrivate = json['is_private'];
    isThumbnailGenerated = json['is_thumbnail_generated'];
    metadata = json['metadata'] != null
        ? new Metadata.fromJson(json['metadata'])
        : null;
    name = json['name'];
    sharedBy = json['shared_by'];
    sizeInBytes = json['size_in_bytes'];
    tags = json['tags'].cast<String>();
    thumbnailUrl = json['thumbnail_url'];
    title = json['title'];
    type = json['type'];
    uploadDate = json['upload_date'];
    uploadStatus = json['upload_status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['asset_id'] = this.assetId;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['is_private'] = this.isPrivate;
    data['is_thumbnail_generated'] = this.isThumbnailGenerated;
    if (this.metadata != null) {
      data['metadata'] = this.metadata.toJson();
    }
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['shared_by'] = this.sharedBy;
    data['size_in_bytes'] = this.sizeInBytes;
    data['tags'] = this.tags;
    data['thumbnail_url'] = this.thumbnailUrl;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['upload_date'] = this.uploadDate;
    data['upload_status'] = this.uploadStatus;
    return data;
  }
}

class Metadata {
  int exifOffset;
  int imageLength;
  int imageWidth;
  int lightSource;
  int orientation;

  Metadata(
      {this.exifOffset,
        this.imageLength,
        this.imageWidth,
        this.lightSource,
        this.orientation});

  Metadata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    exifOffset = json['ExifOffset'];
    imageLength = json['ImageLength'];
    imageWidth = json['ImageWidth'];
    lightSource = json['LightSource'];
    orientation = json['Orientation'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['ExifOffset'] = this.exifOffset;
    data['ImageLength'] = this.imageLength;
    data['ImageWidth'] = this.imageWidth;
    data['LightSource'] = this.lightSource;
    data['Orientation'] = this.orientation;
    return data;
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Get Assets';

    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
        future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotosList({Key? key, required this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Photo> photos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemCount: photos.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(photos[index].thumbnailUrl);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

in Gridview Builder ... thumbnail images are not loading and it is throwing error.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I want the result like this
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnyaj.gif

Comment: can you add the error here?

Comment: I am struggling  to convert json string to Dart Dynamic Map String

Comment: Error is :  CircularProgressIndicator() //// showing rotating on the screen

Comment: in My Console  : I/flutter (20249): {"assets":[{"asset_id":"f1f83e12-364f-4ba3-b173-a22b68cf6f25","created_at":"2021-08-08T06:14:55.633269","descript
ion":"Test Today Description of the flower image goes here..","is_private":false,"is_thumbnail_generated":true,"metadata":{"ExifOffs
et":62,"ImageLength":480,"ImageWidth":360,"LightSource":0,"Orientation":0},"name":"1628403293360.jpg","shared_by":null,"size_in_byte
s":20550,"tags":["newimgtag"],"thumbnail_url":"

Comment: Another exception was thrown: Each child must be laid out exactly once.

Another exception was thrown: Updated layout information required for RenderErrorBox#1c3c1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT to calculate
semantics.